# jQuery включение и выключение по клику

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток.
Ребята, такой вопрос.
Есть скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.looni').AnyFunc();
});
```

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы при клике переключалось на другой код.
Т.е.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (клик по ссылке)
        $('.looni').AnyFunc();
     else
        $('.looni').AnyFunc2();
});
```

При этом нужно, чтобы при повторном клике менялось в обратном порядке.
Грубоговря типа переключателя. При каждом клике, чтобы менялись функции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Впишите обе функции в [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
$('#knopka').toggle(
    function(e){
        // делай раз!
    },
    function(e){
        // делай два!
    }
);
```

[Работающий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/PSvPd/).

Comment: Тут, добавлю своё слово, есть и очевидные минусы. Инициализировать переменную нужно по 2 раза, если хотим, чтобы она не выходила за рамки toggle.

Comment: В вопросе ни слова про переменные. Не будем гадать, что может ещё понадобиться )

Comment: $('.looni').AnyFunc() добавляет в input поле стандартное значение. а оно не нужно.
да же если сделаю $('.looni').val();, то все равно при фокусе на input вставляется значение. вырезать из самого плагина вставку значения по умолчанию не вариант. а вот $('.looni').AnyFunc('none') убивает стандартный вывод значения. я и подумал, что проще сделать переключалку.

toggle смотрел, то же сразу о нем подумал, но про такой вариант решения не знал. буду иметь в виду. спасибо.

lampa, а что вы имели в виду под инициализацией 2 раза?

Comment: @dropoff http://jsfiddle.net/PSvPd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Существует over 9000 вариантов, вот самый простой и наглядный:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
click = 1 /// объявляем переменную для хранения значения toogle
function ToogleClick()
{
    if(click)
    {
        alert('1'); /// код в случаи 1
        click = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('0'); /// код в случаи 2
        click = 1;
    }
}
    </script>
  </had>
  <body>
    <div onclick="ToogleClick();" >click me</div> <!-- вызываем функию -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var click_check = true;

    $('a').click(function() {
        if(click_check) {
            alert(1);
        }
        else {
            alert(2);
        }

        click_check = !click_check;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Alexander Sergeev так правильней, да. Но всё равно, вариант бы срабатывал на alert(2)