# Кнопка со сменой фона при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите с кодом. При нажатии цвет кнопки меняется. При повторном нажатии возвращается прежний цвет.
Своего кода нет. Напишите свой простейший
javascript html

Comment: покажите свой код а то ванговать не охота

Comment: Своего нет. Надеялся вы напишете самый простой

Comment: Посмотрите [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166846/jquery-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83), похожая ситуация.
А вообще, сначала шерстите документацию и пробуйте сами что-то реализовать, а не просите других сделать это за вас.

Answer (score 2):

Написал самый простой вариант как и вы хотели.

```js
blue.onclick = _ =>  blue.classList.toggle("red");
```

```css
.red {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<button id="blue"  class="blue">btn</button>
```